# Conectar via SSH em outra máquina e executar script

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, shell-script

Estou automatizando tarefas e sou novo em Python, por isso gostaria da ajuda de vocês pois preciso rodar um script Shell em uma outra máquina e este comando eu preciso dar dentro de um código Python.

Pensei em usar algo como:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

 # -*- coding: utf8 -*- 
 import subprocess 

 subprocess.call('ssh user@host', shell=True)
```

Mas fica por isso mesmo, pois não sei como implementaria o Login e a Senha (assim como o `"yes"` da criptografia).

Comment: Acho q vc vai ter que "estudar" um pouco mais. Se vc tem acesso as duas maquinas a melhor coisa a fazer é trabalhar com chaves `rsa` e configurar o arquivo `~/.ssh/config`, assim vc não precisa ficar movimentando senha, nome de usuario e nem mesmo endereço do host, ai para facilitar de vez a sua vida use o [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) e seja feliz.

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar o [plumbum](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plumbum/), caso vc queira ir pelo caminho aparentemente mais facil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu imagino que você queira fazer uma conexão SSH  via python. Caso seja isso o módulo pxssh faz exatamente o que você deseja.
Por exemplo, para executar 'ls -l' e para imprimir a saída, você precisa fazer algo assim:

```
import pxssh
s = pxssh.pxssh()
if not s.login ('localhost', 'myusername', 'mypassword'):
    print "SSH falha no login."
    print str(s)
else:
    print "SSH sucesso no login"
    s.sendline ('ls -l')
    s.prompt()         
    print s.before     
    s.logout()
```

Alguns links úteis:

http://dsnra.jpl.nasa.gov/software/Python/site-packages/Contrib/pxssh.html
http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect

Comment: Fiz isso o que você falou e usei as chaves rsa. Realmente ajudou muito. A dificuldade agora é executar os comandos linux dentro da máquina que foi acessada. Meu código simples ficou assim:

##############################################
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import subprocess

subprocess.call('echo Executando Shell dentro do Python', shell=True)
subprocess.call('ssh <user>@<localhost>', shell=True)
subprocess.call('echo Estou na <localhost>', shell=True)
#########################################

Ele acessa a máquina, mas dentro dela não o echo.